Are there any mediapipe python code for multiclass selfie segmentation?
When running the demo of selfie segmentation,
it seems that simple selfie segmentation fails to tell man's head from chair. Multiclass selfie segmentation works greatly so that I want to implement the model. However, it seems that the mediapipe library does not support any functions for it.
mp_human_seg = mp.solutions.selfie_segmentation.SelfieSegmentation()
result_selfie = mp_man_seg.process(image)
                self_seg = np.array(result_selfie.segmentation_mask)
                #print(np.max(self_seg),np.min(self_seg),type(self_seg))
                self_seg[self_seg<0.5]=0
                cv2.imshow('segMask',self_seg)
                cv2.waitKey(1)

The picture following is result of running this code. I marked the chair part that is classified as human body. In case of multiclass selfie segmentation demo, it is clearly eliminated.
I want not to install tensorflow module but only mediapipe, since tensorflow makes the program heavy. Is there anyone that has experience of implementing multiclass selfie segmentation from mediapipe ?
I downloaded the weight file the published.

